# Regular expression validates a sequence of points in a url. Dart

Tags: regex

I have the regex:

```dart
^(https?:\/\/|(www\.))[-a-z0-9]{1,256}\.[a-z0-9]{2,6}+([-a-z0-9())@:%_\+\.\/~#&?=]*[^(?=(.\s()@:%_\+.\/~#&?=))])?$
```

and I'm trying to check the url, but this regular expression checks this invalid url:

```
www.sdf.sdf..d.....d
```

how can I find a sequence of dots and delete this url?

minimal regex:

```
^www\.[-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,6}+([a-z0-9\.]*[^(?=(.))])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(https?:\/\/|(www\.))?[-a-z0-9]{1,256}\.([a-z0-9]{2,6})+([-a-z0-9())@:%_\+\.\/~#&?=]?[^(?=(\.\s()@:%_\+\/~#&?=))])*$
```

i dont know how it works but is works..